# Viewing a list of Controls associated with a class in Visual Studio IDE

Tags: visual-studio, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

I'm using the form designer in VS.

I placed a **label** on my **form**, and then deleted it's text.
Currently, I can not locate the label.

How do I see a list of controls associated with a given class?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

View --> Other Windows --> Document Outline

Answer (score 2):

If you look in the properties window there should be a dropdown of all the controls on the form. You can select a control you can see and then you should see that control in the dropdown list. Then open the list and find the control you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In your launched **Visual Studio** IDE open:

**I** - **Solution Explorer** with `CTRL+ALT+L`,

**II** - **Document Outline** with `CTRL+ALT+T`.

**III** -  Open any class from the **Solution Explorer** to see the **Document Outline** populate accordingly.