# C# Label control invisible after clearing its Text property

Tags: c#, label, controls

I created a `Label` control, I also remove its default value for its `Text` property. Now the label control becomes invisible that I couldn't even select it in `From[Design]`. So I am wondering is there a way to view all the controls/resource created like `MFC` and how can I regain selection of the label control.

cheers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152010/is-there-a-list-of-controls-placed-on-the-current-form-in-visual-studio-2005?

Comment: I always put in a few spaces to keep it handy in the designer after removing the default text..

Comment: Simplest fix is to pay attention to the this.Design property in the OnPaint() method override and draw place-holder text.